# C++ How to resize a Pointer Array to add new values the best?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, methods

Hello people I have to create a program for class which should store Float Values in one pointer array in a class. I looked up how pointers work and l think l got it. Or maybe I didn't? because my code does weired stuff.

```
 private:
        float * messdaten;
        int mdi = 0;
    public:
        CMesswerte(){

        }
        void setDaten(float  daten[], int size) {
            float* temparray;
                temparray = new float[mdi];
                for(int i=0; i < mdi; i++){
                *(temparray + i) = *(messdaten + i);
                }
                messdaten = new float[size+mdi];
                for(int i=0; i < mdi; i++)
                *(messdaten + i) = *(temparray + i);
                for(int i=mdi; i < mdi+size; i++) {
                *(messdaten + i) = daten[i]; 
            }
            mdi=mdi+size;
        }
```

So the floating pointer variable `messdaten` should store all stuff, and the integer `mdi` is a counter on the "current size" of the pointer.
The Method `setDaten` gets an array with some floats that is then stored in `messdaten` (daten) and the size of the array (size) to create it at runtime.
Then all Data from `messdaten` gets stored in `temparray` so I can delete `messdaten` to create it with the new correct size. After it everything gets transfered over to `messdaten` again.
When I run the code I get:

These two arrays are passed in two separate fuction calls:

```
float Daten_1[5] = { 1.5, 2.3, 5.5, 0.6, 7.5};
float Daten_3[5] = {2.4, 1.5, 5.4, 2.3, 7.5};
```

And this is the output I get:

```
1 - 1.5
2 - 2.3
3 - 5.5
4 - 0.6
5 - 7.5
6 - 0
7 - 3.36312e-44
8 - 0
9 - 1.5
10 - 2.3
```

But I get a wrong output? and I don't get why... please help.
(note I am not allowed to use vectors)

Comment: yes because this is supposed to be an excersise on how to use pointers in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
                *(messdaten + i) = daten[i];
```

is wrong. The index for `daten` should start from 0, but here it actually starts from `mdi`.

It should be:

```
                *(messdaten + i) = daten[i - mdi];
```

Another option is changing

```
                for(int i=mdi; i < mdi+size; i++) {
                *(messdaten + i) = daten[i]; 
            }
```

to

```
                for(int i=0; i < size; i++) {
                *(messdaten + size + i) = daten[i]; 
            }
```

Also to avoid memory leak:

- Add `delete[] temparray;` at the end of function `setDaten`.
- Add initialization of `messdaten` to `nullptr` and add `delete[] messdaten;` before `messdaten = new float[size+mdi];`.

Comment: hi first, thank you. i already tried using the "delete" statements before at the right positions, but when i use them for some reason, i dont get any output, when i smash messdaten through my function that simply outputs the values. Am i doing something wrong? and what dou you mean with "Add initialization of messdaten to nullptr"? Should i do this: "float * messdaten = nullptr"??? Thx

Comment: Not following [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) will cause trouble when objects are copied. Your understanding about initialization is right.